# How to test given code using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, tdd

I want to test that `fan.setState` method is called or not

```
class OffState implements State {

    @Override
    public void changeState(Fan fan) {
        fan.setState(new OnState());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OffStateTest {

    @Mock
    private Fan fan;

    @Test
    public void testChangeState() {
        //Arrange
        OffState offState = new OffState();

        //Act
        offState.changeState(fan);

        //Assert
        Mockito.verify(fan).setState(Mockito.any(OnState.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nkosi: I was assuming the `OnState.equals()` method would cover this. I started writing an ArgumentCaptor form of the test case but felt that might only confuse matters. Anyway, using `Mockito.any()` is the simplest way of making it pass and the OP can move on to a custom matcher or ArgumentCaptor if needed. Thanks!

Comment: But if i used any of verify(fan).setState(Mockito.any(OffState.class)); or verify(fan).setState(Mockito.any(OnState.class)); still it works